# How to review this "low quality" answer?

Tags: discussion, support, review

This perhaps feels more like a general Stack Exchange "problem", but anyway...

How do I review the following [answer that was flagged as "low quality"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/144732) - it doesn't seem possible to "complete" the review task?

[image: Low quality answer - review queue]

It was evidently flagged because it's a code-only solution that provides no explanation. None of the available options would seem to apply:

- "Looks OK" - Well, no, it provides no explanation.
- "Edit" - It certainly needs editing - but I shouldn't be the one to edit it (to basically spend time answering the question, if indeed I know how to answer the question).
- "Recommend deletion" - AFAIK the answer is "correct". And it is referenced by the other "accepted" answer stating that it works (except for some caveats). So if it was deleted, the other "accepted" answer would be *incomplete*.

As it stands, I left a comment to prompt the user to provide further explanation, but this is not sufficient to "complete" the review task.

So, how should this type of review task be "reviewed"?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** should be used mostly to fix "small" problems like markdown, spelling, grammar, terminology, among other "small" issues but not to fix major content problems like a missing description of what the formula does, etc.

**Deletion** should be used on "answers" that do not answer the question, queries that should be posted as a question, not for *answers* that have missing a description of what the formula does, etc.

In this case you could select **Looks OK**. This will make that anyone will be able to see the answer<sup>1</sup> and remove it from the review queue or click on **Skip**, this will keep the post hidden from guests (no signed in users) and on the review queue.

NOTES:

1. I'm not sure if this is actually working on this site.

Related

- [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/289691)

Comment: Except that "Looks OK" does rather contradict that it is "low quality" and does need to be fixed. (I thought in the past it was possible to leave a constructive comment in order to satisfy the review task? Can't say I'm a fan of the new "review queue workflows".) And "Skip" simply _ignores_ the problem. Users want to complete a review task - so end up picking any "wrong" option in order to do so, rather than "Skip". Incidentally, I do not believe "low quality" answers are hidden from guests (on any site)?

Comment: UPDATE: It seems another user had already(?) reviewed this particular "low quality post" and (incorrectly) selected "Recommend Deletion" (although in the absence of better options this is understandable and really a problem with the review process IMO). A few hours after I posted my comment the OP responded and thoroughly updated their answer, making it (what appears to be) a good answer. Not sure what happens to the "Recommend Deletion" review in this case? (Unfortunately, the 2 users that had previously downvoted the answer don't appear to be following it in order to undownvote.)